# Open Navigator after clicked on a Rss Reader

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, rss-reader

i have a news reader (using rss), it's work as well, now i'm trying to open the navigator after clicked on a news, but i don't know how to get the link (i just know that i have to use getLink() but i don't know where):

Actualites.java

```
public class Actualites extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List> a = null;
    NewsAdapter adapter = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_actualites, container, false);
        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<News>());
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.solutis.fr")));
            }
        });
        a = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List>() {
            @Override
            protected List doInBackground(Void... params) {
                ArrayList<News> res = new ArrayList<News>();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.solutis.fr/actualites-rachat-credit,rss.html?format=feed");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    RssParser parser = new RssParser();
                    try {
                        return parser.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return res;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List result) {
                adapter.update(result);
            }
        };
        a.execute();
        TextView textView =(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar_title);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.title_actu));
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
        return view;
    }
}
```

NewsAdapter.java

```
public class NewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<News> news;
    Context context;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> news) {
        this.news = news;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void update(List<News> news) {
        this.news = news;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return news.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return news.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.three_line_list_item, null);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBold.ttf"));
        tv1.setTextSize(15);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2B729F"));
        tv3.setTextSize(13);
        tv3.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        tv2.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/GothamBook.ttf"));
        tv2.setTextSize(14);
        News n = (News)getItem(arg0);
        tv1.setText(n.getTitle());
        String pubDate =  Html.fromHtml(n.getPubDate()).toString().replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim();
        tv3.setText(pubDate);
        String content = Html.fromHtml(n.getContent()).toString().replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim();
        tv2.setText(content);
        return v;
    }
}
```

RssParser.java

```
public class RssParser {
    private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String result = "";
        if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            result = parser.getText();
            parser.nextTag();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static final String ns = null;

    private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<News> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        ArrayList<News> entries = new ArrayList<News>();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
        parser.nextTag();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "channel");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();
            if (name.equals("item")) {
                String title = "";
                String link = "";
                String pubDate = "";
                String content = "";
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("title")) {
                        title = readText(parser);
                    } else if (name.equals("link")) {
                        link = readText(parser);
                    } else if (name.equals("pubDate")) {
                        pubDate = readText(parser);
                    } else if (name.equals("description")) {
                        content = readText(parser);
                    } else
                        skip(parser);
                }
                entries.add(new News(title, pubDate, content));
            }  else
                skip(parser);
        }
        return entries;
    }
}
```

News.java

```
public class News {
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String pubDate;
    private String link;

    public News(String title, String pubDate, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public News(String link, String title, String pubDate, String content) {
        this.link = link;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return (title);
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return (content);
    }

    public String getPubDate(){
        return (pubDate);
    }

    public String getLink(){
        return (link);
    }
}
```

I have to change public void onItemClick(), i've just put a url, but i have to get the url of the news, but i don't know how to do that. Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the news object from the adapter using the position parameter in the onItemClick.  I haven't tested the code but it will be something like the following;

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                News news = (News) adapter.getItem(position)
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(news.getLink())));
            }
```

Comment: I get a error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
            at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:464)
            at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:454)
            at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:426)
            at package.Actualites$1.onItemClick(Actualites.java:37)

I think its because its not a string

Comment: Just noticed that in your RSSParser you are calling entries.add(new News(title, pubDate, content));  You need to call the version that accepts the link and pass that through as well.
I'd suggest you put a breakpoint on the onItemClick and check your news object returned.

Comment: In the RSSParser i don't call link in the entries because i don't want to display the link on the view.
The version that accept the link ? i put the breakpoint, i have the good position of the news, but when i put the cursor on getLink() i see nothing.

Comment: If i do
String url = (String) news.getLink();
i get url: null

Comment: I dont know why but if i do

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(news.getTitle())));

Its work...

Comment: I cannot see the RSS data you are retrieving so don't know what title and link contains but sounds like you have worked it out.  The key part was using the adapter.getItem(position) to get the current item, whatever data it contains.  If you find this answer acceptable please accept it to increase both our reputations.

Comment: I changed a little my code and its work :
Actualites.java:
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                News news = (News) adapter.getItem(position);
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(news.getLink())));
            }
RssParser.java
entries.add(new News(link, title, pubDate, content));

And we dont see the link in the view and when we click on which on its work.

Comment: I could not see why link would be showing on the view when you first suggested it.  Glad you got it sorted.